# Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Any]' with an argument of type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey'

Tags: ios, xcode11, swift5

I'm trying to figure how to update my code to support the new way that UIImagePickerController() works in Swift 5

I was able to fix the same error in another section of my code here:

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
        guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else { return }
        let sellLandingVC = navigationController.topViewController as? SellLandingViewController
        sellLandingVC?.viewModel.insertSelectedImage(image)
        navigationController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Here is my code and my error is showing up when calling **imagePicker.rx.didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo.map**

```
private func setupRx() {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

        Observable.combineLatest(checkIfPermissionIsGranted(), captureButton.rx.tap) { (isGranted, _ ) in return isGranted }
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] isGranted in
                self?.captureButton.pulsate()
                if !isGranted {
                    self?.displayAlert(with: self?.viewModel.accessDeniedTitle, message: self?.viewModel.accessDeniedMessage, actions: [UIAlertAction.cancel(), UIAlertAction.settings()])
                } else {
                    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
                    self?.present(imagePicker, animated: true)
                }
            })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        imagePicker.rx.didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo
            .map {
               $0[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
//This is where I'm getting the error
            }
            .map {
                ProfilePictureCommand.setImage($0)
            }
            .bind(to: viewModel.concurrentCommandSubject)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        viewModel.stateObservable
            .map {
                $0.userImage ?? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "email-signup-avatar")
        }
            .bind(to: profileImageView.rx.image)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        imagePicker.rx.didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo
            .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
                imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true)
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        viewModel.stateObservable
            .map {
                return $0.isContinueEnabled
            }
            .bind(to: continueButton.rx.isEnabled)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        viewModel.stateObservable
            .map {
                return $0.isContinueEnabled
            }
            .map {
                $0 ? UIColor.colorHex303030(alpha: 1.0) : UIColor.colorHexC5C5C5(alpha: 1.0)
            }
            .bind(to: continueButton.rx.scBackgroundColor)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        continueButton.rx.tap
            .map { ProfilePictureCommand.next }
            .bind(to: viewModel.concurrentThrottleCommandSubject)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your version of rx is giving you a `[String:Any]` instead of a `[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]`. `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey` is now an enum with a case `.originalImage`. If you want to subscript the old fashioned way with a string just ask for the raw value: `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage.rawValue`

```
 $0[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage.rawValue] as! UIImage
```